# Android Questions about Mozilla GeckoView

Tags: android, webview, geckoview

I am a beginner Android developer.
I using the 'WebView' had tried to make a Android App.
However, the speed of the web is too slow.
So the Internet search results found GeckoView.
But homepage has been difficult for me to understand I do not know English well.

My questions:

1. Can I use GeckoView instead of the WebView? Is it simple?
2. Can I use a code library that just adds to the 'build.gradle' in Android Studio?
3. Is there another altenative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Gecko view is only experimental.  You can't use for production 
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView

So your only choice would be a webview. If you are great in javascript, I would recommend you to use react-native. This is how facebook is made, and you can follow extensive documents mentioned here. 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/
```

Comment: Thank you!  It was very helpful to me.

Comment: This answer is now out of date.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use GeckoView also....
Android WebView is not intended for building browser application because, many advanced Web API'S are disabled.
And different phones might have different versions of WebView all of which your app has to support....

Geckoview is open source library that allows you to render web content on Android using the Gecko web engine...

I made simple application with webview, just check out you'll get some help
https://github.com/malikhimani21/Project-2

In some cases, a WebView is a good option for displaying trusted first-party access to your web pages from either a browser or your own app
 check out this link 
https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps

Comment: but the problem here is GeckoView does not support Javascript evaluation do u have any solution for that ?